# Unable to start a docker container in daemon mode

Tags: docker

This is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y emacs npm git nodejs

RUN rm -rf  .emacs .emacs.d
RUN git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.emacs.d

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

RUN npm install && npm install -g yarn
```

I tried to start it in daemon mode so I can attach to the process later on

```
docker run -d spacemacs bash
```

But it fails to stay resident

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
d4f867eb78f1        spacemacs                 "bash"              3 minutes ago       Exited (0) 3 minutes ago                        loving_turing
```

Why it is the case? I have run other container in daemon mode before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docker run -d spacemacs bash
```

You ran the command `bash` with no input, so it exited. The same happens if you do this on a normal linux prompt:

```
$ bash </dev/null
$ echo $?
0
```

If you want to later attach to a running bash shell, you can tell docker that the command is interactive so that it keeps stdin open. I'd also recommend allocating a tty:

```
docker run -dit spacemacs bash
```